# react navtive this.props all value programatically

Tags: react-native

My question is simple.

I want to know all the keys of

this.props

This is react native props of my React Component

```
export default class TapBar extends React.Component{
   constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.props.what?
  }
}
```

Sometimes this.props has key of 'a' or 'b' or 'navigation'

Sometimes not depending of usage.

How can I print console all of it?

Answer (score 1):

here you can console link this according to your code

```
export default class TapBar extends React.Component{
       constructor(props)
      {
        super(props);
        console.log(props) // find what you want
      }
    }
```

Comment: Provide description for your answer